# Solucionado: Problema con React-Query Mutación

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

El problema que tengo es que la mutación no se está realizando y no se el por que según la [documentación de react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/optimistic-updates).

Primer error que me sale es que `const previusUsers = queryClient.getQueryData(["users"]);` devuelve `undefined`

Segundo error producido por el primero creo, al devolver `undefined` entra al metodo `OnError` el cual sus dejo en comentarios lo que devuelve cada parametro

```
onError: (err, newData, context) => {
  console.log(err, newData, context?.previusUsers);
  // err:SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'N', "Not Found" is not valid JSON
  // newData: {email: 'leni.johansson@example.com', id: 1}
  // context?.previusUsers undefined
  queryClient.setQueryData(["users"], context?.previusUsers);
},
```

Tercer Error la mutación no se produce, tengo entendido que la mutación se produce dentro de `onMutate` en especifico aquí:

```
const result = queryClient.setQueryData(["users"], () => {
  return {
    pages: [{ users: userFilters }],
    pageParams: [data?.pageParams],
  };
});
```

la llamada la hago de esta forma, esta función es la que exporto para otros componentes:

```
const deleteData = (email: string) => {
  mutation.mutate({ email, id: 1 });
};
```

Dejo el enlace a GitHub para mas detalles [[repositorio actualizado]](https://github.com/FrancoEspinozaV/ReactProject/blob/error-delete-data/09-Prueba-Tecnica-Country/src/hooks/useUsers.tsx)

Editado: estoy utilizando `useInfiniteQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Solución

Primero `const previusUsers = queryClient.getQueryData(["users"])` devuelve undefined, por que se esta haciendo mal la llamada estaba utilizando `const queryClient = new QueryClient` y es `const queryClient = useQueryClient()`

Segundo entra en `onError` porque la petición de la api utilizada retorna un 400 es decir se está haciendo mal la consulta. para arreglar la consulta solo seguí la documentación de la API.

Tercero no se funcionaba el setQueryData por la mal invocación del queryClient